# Switch Temperature - How hot it too hot!

Tags: switch, dell, best-practices

I've got a few network switches running rather hot. The switches have an average internal temperature of 63°C. I'm aware that this is too hot for a network switches and we are pushing upper management for air con. My question is this, what temperature would you expect to see a switch running at whilst running under load? What would you argue is best practice when it comes to internal switch temperatures? If it helps the switch models are Dell N4032.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on your device, if temperature is high, fans will spin faster and you reduce timelife of your switch.

I think 63°C is slightly high but I have switches working at this temperature (or greater) with no problems.

If you need a number, according N4000 manual, front led is triggered when "The thermal sensor’s system temperature threshold of 75°C has been exceeded." So, you are reaching limit but you still have a security margin.

Comment: Hi KorXo. Thanks for your reply. Interesting to hear that you have switches running at that temperature and above. I touched the outer casing on them this morning and I could have fried an egg on them! It looks like we have no major worries until the LED comes on.

Comment: Anyway, you should try to cool down this devices by separating devices, check correct cabling, improve refrigeration, etc. My first sentence should be: lower temperature, better performance and durability. In summary, try to cool down. If you can't, don't worry much about it.

Comment: Agreed. Unfortunately I'm in the situation where upper management believe it's not hot enough to justify the expense of having air con installed. The team I work in are trying to prove the case for air con. We have set a data logger up collecting temperature and humidity levels up.